# JQuery script works on Firefox but throws "undefined is not a function" in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string, dom

Trying to write a simple if statement that alert yes if true and no if not true. It is working in Firefox but not Chrome.

```
<ul class="sidea" role="tablist">
    <a href="scripts/featured.php" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" class="ajax-link" id="defaultclick">
        <li role="presentation" class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4 categoryb1">
            <div class="categoryb arrow_box">Featured</div>
        </li>
    </a>
</ul>
```

JQuery:

```
if (($('a.ajax-link').html()).contains('Featured1')){
  alert("yes");
}
else {
  alert("no");
}
```

Comment: What is expected result ? Is "Featured1" text , or `DOM` `element` ?

Comment: With this the result I expect would be an alert "no" (which works on Firefox) when I change it to just Featured I get the Yes alert (in Firefox). This is on my main page. I have Jquery and Bootstrap libraries loaded. I simplified my if statement to this to troubleshoot a larger if statement I was writing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`elem.contains(elem)` finds whether an element contains another DOM element.
It does not check if a string contains a string.

To do that, use `string.indexOf(string)` instead. If it is more than or equal 0, means the search string is within the haystack. Note that this is case-sensitive, so you may want to make both lowercase first.

Example:

```
if ( ($('a.ajax-link').html()).indexOf('Featured1') >= 0 ){
```

---

**Bonus Helpful Hint:**

You should log debug messages to console instead, you can explore arrays and objects this way, and it won't pause the JS main thread.

```
console.log($('a.ajax-link').html());
```

Answer (score 1):

`contains()` seems to be a Firefox peculiarity.  I can't find any documentation of it whatsoever.

Use `indexOf() > -1` instead.